# Testing update action in Phoenix framework

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to test my controller's "update" action.

But whenever I try:

```
conn =
  put(
    conn,
    Routes.club_item_path(conn, :update, item.club_id, item.id),
    @update_attrs)
```

or

```
conn =
  put(
    conn,
    Routes.club_item_path(conn, :update, item.club_id, item.id),
    item: @update_attrs)
```

I always get:

```
 ** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

Which is odd, because when testing the "create" action I did:

```
conn =
  post(
    conn,
    Routes.club_item_path(conn, :create, club.id),
    item: @create_attrs )
```

And it worked without a problem. I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding something about path helpers in Phoenix.

Comment: Post the results of `$ mix phx.routes`.

Comment: Also please post the full error message with stacktrace!